# Take string input, parse each word to all lowercase and print each word on a line, non-alphabetic characters are treated as a break between words

Tags: java, string, algorithm, parsing, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to take a string input, parse each word to all lowercase and print each word on a line (in sorted order), ignoring non-alphabetic characters (single letter words count as well). So,

Sample input:

```
Adventures in Disneyland

Two blondes were going to Disneyland when they came to a fork in the
road. The sign read: "Disneyland Left."

So they went home.
```

Output:

```
a
adventures
blondes
came
disneyland
fork
going
home
in
left
read
road
sign
so
the
they
to
two
went
were
when
```

My program:

```
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String word = reader.next();
            if (word != "") {
                word = word.toLowerCase();
                word = word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "");
                if (!words.contains(word)) {
                    words.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(words);
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(words.get(i));
        }
```

This works for the input above, but prints the wrong output for an input like this:

```
a  t\|his@ is$ a)( -- test's-&*%$#-`case!@|?
```

The expected output should be

```
a
case
his
is
s
t
test
```

The output I get is

```
*a blank line is printed first*
a
is
testscase
this
```

So, my program obviously doesn't work since scanner.next() takes in characters until it hits a whitespace and considers that a string, whereas anything that is not a letter should be treated as a break between words. I'm not sure how I might be able to manipulate Scanner methods so that breaks are considered non-alphabetic characters as opposed to whitespace, so that's where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: How does `a  t\|his@` translate to `a case his`?

Comment: "case" is from the part says that "case" in the input. a, t and his are treated as separate words because they're separated by non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer has already mentioned some issues with your code.

I suggest another approach to address your requirements. Such transformations are a good use case for Java Streams – it often yields clean code:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.stream(input.split("[^A-Za-Z]+"))
    .map(t -> t.toLowerCase())
    .distinct()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here are the steps:

1. Split the string by one or more subsequent characters not being alphabetic;

   ```
   input.split("[^A-Za-Z]+")
   ```

   This yields *tokens* consistint solely of alphabetic characters.
2. Stream over the resulting array using `Arrays.stream()`;
3. Map each element to their lowercase equivalent:

   ```
   .map(t -> t.toLowerCase())
   ```

   The default locale is used. Use `toLowerCase(Locale)` to explicitly set the locale.
4. Discard duplicates using `Stream.distinct()`.
5. Sort the elements within the stream by simply calling `sorted()`;
6. Collect the elements into a `List` with `collect()`.

---

If you need to read it from a file, you could use this:

```
Files.lines(filepath)
    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("[^A-Za-Z]+")))
    .map(... // Et cetera
```

But if you need to use a `Scanner`, then you could be using something like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input)
    .useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]+");
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNext()) {
    parts.add(s.next());
}
```

And then

```
List<String> strs = parts.stream()
    .map(... // Et cetera
```

Comment: What would be "input"? I'm technically supposed to be reading input from standard input (System.in), I'm just reading it from a text file in my code right now for debugging purposes. So I'm not sure how that would factor into your solution.

Comment: @J.Doe `input` is simply a `String`.

Comment: So "input" is the entire text input?

Comment: @J.Doe Yep, as a String. I will adapt my answer to also include the Scanner.

Comment: So the "parts" list is initiated correctly, but upon doing .stream().map etc., the list isn't affected at all.

Comment: You forgot to save it into a new list

Comment: So when transforming a String input, generally always use Java Streams?

Comment: @J.Doe *Generally*, yes. In my opinion using the streams API often leads to clean and concise code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189158/discussion-between-mc-emperor-and-j-doe).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==` or `!=` for comparing `String`(s). Also, perform your transform **before** you check for empty. This,

```
if (word != "") {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    word = word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "");
    if (!words.contains(word)) {
        words.add(word);
    }
}
```

should look something like

```
word = word.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", "").trim();
if (!word.isEmpty() && !words.contains(word)) {
    words.add(word);
}
```